# How to Exact String value out side of tag xml or html and I have to store it in list using java?

Tags: java, string, extract

I am having string like

```
String str="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><head><heading>Appliance Repairs</heading></head><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Appliance Repairs<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Air conditioning and refrigeration services<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Accountants<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Accident Management"
```

Here I have to extract only the string which was present outside of the tag.
output I required here is given below::

```
Appliance Repairs
Appliance Repairs
Air conditioning and refrigeration services
Accident Management
```

And I have to store these value into List, help me for this .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SAXParser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). Inherit your handler from [`DefaultHandlder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html), and override [`characters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to concatenate string parts coming from the parser (you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for that).

Clear the builder in  `startElement`; add the finished string to your list in `endElement`.

Here is a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) to a quick tutorial on parsing XML in Java using SAX parser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regular expressions. I think that regex are so useful that there is no sense in writing the direct solution to your problem. I would recommend you to get familiar with them and try them out on your own. In the future you will be using regex quite often so there is no sense in cutting corners. Here is a quite good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Using regex on HTML/XML is not a good idea (see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/335858)). Even if you get it right for a simple case, a tricky one will blow up on you.